# Can't subclass with ES6 / babel-node

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have the following files: [gist](https://gist.github.com/ksnyde/f7c8cb6044b8936f2dd1)

The **index.js** attempts instantiate a base "Auth" class but in it's constructor the auth class acts as an object factory and passes back a subclass of Auth instead.

```
'use strict';
import Auth from './Auth';

let o = new Auth({type:'Oauth1'});
console.log(o);
o.getToken();
```

The **Auth.js** class definition is as follows:

```
'use strict';
import Oauth1 from './Oauth1';

export default class Auth {
    constructor(config) {
        if (this instanceof Auth) {
            return new Oauth1(config);
        } else {
            this.config = config;
        }
    }

    getToken() {
        console.log('Error: the getToken module must be implemented in the subclass');
    }
}
```

And the **Oauth1.js** class definition is:

```
'use strict';
import Auth from './Auth';

export default class Oauth1 extends Auth {
    getToken() {
        console.log('Auth: ', Auth);
    }
}
```

When running with `babel-node index.js` I get the following error:

> **TypeError**: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

```
at _inherits (/repos/mine/test-app/Oauth1.js:1:14)
at /repos/mine/test-app/Oauth1.js:4:28
at Object.<anonymous> (/repos/mine/test-app/Oauth1.js:4:28)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at normalLoader (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
```

If I remove the `extends` expression from the Oauth1 class it executes but then I am not getting the inheritance I want.

Comment: `new Auth` should not return a `Oauth1`. Why don't you simply import and instantiate `Oauth` in your index.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with `babel`. The real problem is that you have [circular dependencies](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles) in your code.

To resolve this issue you should remove `Oauth1` dependency from its parent `Auth` class:

```
'use strict';
export default class Auth {
    constructor(config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    getToken() {
        console.log('Error: the getToken module must be implemented in the subclass');
    }
}
```

```
'use strict';
import Auth from './Auth';

export default class Oauth1 extends Auth {
    getToken() {
        console.log('Auth: ', Auth);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to remove `this instanceof Auth` check from your base class, you could `require` your `Oauth1` subclass in run-time instead of importing it during module initialization:

```
constructor(config) {
    if (this instanceof Auth) {
        let Oauth1 = require('./Oauth1');
        return new Oauth1(config);
    }
    this.config = config;
}
```

Comment: So is there no way to achieve the desired "factory" effect of instantiating the base class and having it return the best subclass based on the configuration passed in? How about if I just had the base class have a static method which served as the factory?

Comment: I see and it does work for me that way but I loose my factory pattern, I guess I can still have a separate factory object which does that though.

Comment: If you want/need the circular dependency, the original code would work if only the `Oauth1.js` module was imported before the `Auth.js` one.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny is run-time linking with require a possibility in ES6? I think the module system is static as a recognised compromise for now (with a future ... ES7? ... release bringing back runtime where needed. Could be my misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I've kept it out for now but it's nice to know this option exists where needed

Comment: @ken `require` is a part of `CommonJS` modules specification and should work in any `CommonJS` environment (e.g. `node.js`, `browserify`, `webpack`, etc.).

Comment: so babel doesn't reject in transpilation?  I thought I remembered that but if not it's nice to have this in the back pocket.

Comment: @ken: No, it just transpiles the function call to a function call. It might however not recognise it as a module import, and does no ES6 module dependency magic stuff - that's left to the CommonJS environment.