# ES6 modules and inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I have the following JavaScript files:

**src/js/classes/Lexus.js:**

```
import {Car} from 'src/js/classes/Car';

export class Lexus extends Car {
  constructor() {
    super("Lexus");
  }
}
```

**src/js/classes/Mercedes.js:**

```
import {Car} from 'src/js/classes/Car';

export class Mercedes extends Car {
  constructor() {
    super("Mercedes");
  }
}
```

**src/js/classes/Car.js:**

```
import {Lexus} from 'src/js/classes/Lexus'; //either of those imports works, but not both!
import {Mercedes} from 'src/js/classes/Mercedes'; //either of those imports works, but not both!

export class Car {
  constructor(make) {
    this.make = make;
  }

  static factory(msg) {
    switch(msg) {
      case "Lexus":
        return new Lexus();
      case "Mercedes":
        return new Mercedes();
    }
  }
}
```

**and app.js:**

```
import {Lexus} from 'src/js/classes/Lexus';
import {Mercedes} from 'src/js/classes/Mercedes';
import {Car} from 'src/js/classes/Car';

var car = Car.factory("Lexus");
console.log(car);
```

The interesting thing, if I import **either** `Lexus` or `Mercedes` to the Car class and call the factory method in app.js - everything works fine; however if I import **both** `Lexus` and `Mercedes` to the Car class I got an error:

> Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

What do I miss ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to import Lexus and Mercedes in the app.js, since they're not constructed there.

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't based off of Car and your specific make classes being circular dependent on each other?

Comment: what happens if you put a break within the cases after each new statement? Edit: nvm youre returning so the switch is out of scope sry

Comment: Sterling Archer, I do need to import Lexus and/or Mercedes to app.js, in order to instantiate from factory method.

Comment: @Binvention, if error based on Car and make classes being circular dependent on each other, how it explain the fact that either imports works, but not both ?

Comment: Why do you mix together `inheritance` and [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) ? Choose one of them. Or use a combination like `Lexus extends Car`, `Mercedes extends Car` and `CarFactory.produce('Lexus')`.

Comment: That would probably be based on what order the scripts run I don't know exactly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't subclass with ES6 / babel-node](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32757083/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, you want to *not* have circular dependencies like this.
Circular dependencies at the best of times, break everything and don't compile (or transpile).
Circular dependencies at the worst of times, cause merge and versioning conflicts, cause code that's really hard to discern, look like they're working just fine, until they stop, with some terrible bug caused by some terrible state assumptions.

Your solution (if you are dead-set on this form of inheritance) is going to be to extract `Car` into its own file/class, which can be imported separately, and to have the Factory be separate from the class.

Which, in English makes complete sense.
Cars don't construct Lexuses (Lexi?).

Additionally, if you *did* want to keep this (not a great idea), then you should have a register method, not a hard-coded solution, whereby you register "Lexus" and the function which makes a new Lexus.

```
import Car from "./car";
class Lexus extends Car {
  constructor () {
    super("Lexus");
  }
  // starting to look like a bad idea
  static make () {
    return Car.make("Lexus");
  }
  // starting to look worse
  static register () {
    /* this register method does nothing, so that Lexus can't make other cars... */
  }
}

Car.register("Lexus", () => new Lexus());

export default Lexus;
```

It gets worse, but this is already plenty bad.

If you go the other route:

```
// carfactory.js

const carTypes = new Map();
class CarFactory {
  static register (name, implementation) {
    carTypes.set(name, implementation);
    return CarFactory;
  }
  static make (name) {
    const makeCar = carTypes.get(name);
    return makeCar();
  }

  register (name, implementation) {
    CarFactory.register(name, implementation);
    return this;
  }
  make (name) { return CarFactory.make(name); }
}

export default CarFactory;


// index.js
import Car from "./classes/car";
import Lexus from "./classes/lexus";

import CarFactory from "./factories/car";

CarFactory
  .register("Lexus", () => new Lexus())
  .register("Bentley", () => new Bentley());

init( CarFactory );

function init (Car) {
  const lexus = Car.make("Lexus");
}
```

Now, no classes need to know about things they shouldn't have to.

Comment: How my Car class should look like if I go 'the other route' ?

Comment: @user3715778 `class Car { constructor (make) { this.make = make; } }`

Comment: and from where Car.make() method comes from ?

Comment: There is no `Car.make` have a close look at the inside of `init`, and what is passed into `init` when it’s called. The point of the factory is that the regular code doesn’t have to know or care that it’s a CarFactory or a Car.  It’s given a thing. It uses the thing, and gets what it expects, so it’s happy.

Comment: `map.set(name, implementation);` inside of register method, should it be `carTypes.set(name, implementation);` instead ?

Comment: Should be. And fixed. I had originally called it `map` while I was trying to figure out what I was trying to say, and refactored it after. Apparently not all of the references.

Comment: Sorry, why do I need init() function if I can just `var lexus = CarFactory.make("Lexus");` ?

Comment: Anyway, thank you sir. Appreciate it. Will mark it as an answer.

Comment: You don’t actually need the `init` for the example. The `init` is a boundary which would be the entry point of your application, separating your bootstrapping/factory-building from your actual work that you were doing with what comes out of the things you’ve instantiated.  The intent is that either side (in real world code) can now be saved/worked on/packaged in two different sets of files without colliding.  Much of this is overkill for a pet project, but becomes more important the larger you get.  The act of passing it in at runtime, rather than inlining it, is “Dependency Inversion”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105952/discussion-between-user3715778-and-norguard).