# Node ES6: class is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to figure out a bug that i've been running into in my code. I wrote out a simple example that replicated the bug using classes a, b and a entry file c.

Where is my code going wrong?

**Edit**

Many of the answers are concerning my code structure! I would like to clarify the functionality that is required.

1. **a:** needs a static instance of b. Therefore, A needs to require B.
2. **b's functions (none static):** only accept objects that are an `instanceof a`. Therefore, B needs to require A.

Specifically, I have a "Phrase" class (a) and a "Parser" class (b). Parser only accepts phrases. Phrase parses its self on creation using its static parser instance.

**a.js**

```
'use strict';

let b = require('./b.js');

class a {
    constructor() {

    }
}

new b();

module.exports = a;
```

**b.js**

```
'use strict';

let a = require('./a.js');

class b {
    constructor() {

    }
}

module.exports = b;
```

**c.js**

```
'use strict';

let b = require('./b.js');
new b();
```

**run:** `node c.js`

**error:**

```
C:\code\a.js:11
new b();
^

TypeError: b is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code\projects\elegance\data-frog\tag\datastructures\a.js:11:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code\projects\elegance\data-frog\tag\datastructures\b.js:3:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

Comment: Which version of Node are you using?

Comment: Using version v5.9.0

Comment: Looking at the edit, for what i know, the only way to do what you need is really to use a third class as i illustrate on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

### Update

Based upon your edit, my immediate suggestion is that you continue to use `class Phrase` if you choose to keep it, specifically because you like having the ability to log the type of an object...
...but to use that constructor as nothing more than a `struct` that you would find in other languages.

Your `Parser` can know about `Phrase`s, given that it parses them, but there's really 0 harm in having the parser accept duck-typed entries, as the difference in flexibility is large, if you check for the interface your method wants (fields on the struct that you actually use), versus checking for a strict instance.

A quick example may be loading a list of phrases from a web service. Do you really need to instantiate every line as a phrase, before parsing them?

Here's an example of how you might handle the case in which you have a low-level struct, which doesn't really need a factory for DI (because it's so low-level), but rather, could be directly imported into the `Parser` module.

```
// phrase.js
class Phrase {
  constructor (content = "") {
    this.content = content;
  }

  static from (phrase) {
    return new Phrase(phrase.content);
  }

  static isPhrase (phrase) {
    return phrase && phrase.content !== null && phrase.content !== undefined;
  }
}

export default Phrase; // or module.exports


// parser.js
import Parser from "./parser"; // or require, whatever floats your boat
class Parser {
  static parse ( input = "" ) {
    const preparedContent = Phrase.isPhrase( input )
      ? Parser.prepareContent( input.content )
      : Parser.prepareContent( input );

    return new Phrase(content);
  }

  static prepareContent ( input = "" ) {
    // ...
  }

  parse (content) {
    return Parser.parse(content);
  }
}

export default Parser;
```

I can now make an instance of `Parser` or just statically use it.
I can hand it raw input, or I can hand it a Phrase, and it will do the right thing.
Moreover, I'm not relying on Parser to be able to define what Phrase is. Parser is relying on a Phrase builder to know what Phrase is.

Parser is always returning a new instance of a "parsed" Phrase, but its input is now more relaxed. As well, based on what is coming in, you can now do more-sane things with your input (ie: provide good defaults, like safely returning an empty phrase (where `phrase.content` in my example world might be an empty string), rather than returning `null` or throwing, based on an instanceof).

---

Have a look at an answer which I provided elsewhere, for further details (and check the question to see where he hit a similar roadblock exactly one stop beyond where you are, currently).

[ES6 modules and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903857/es6-modules-and-inheritance/35904540#35904540)

The answer, though, is that you should not be relying on circular dependencies, which will do terrible, terrible things to your codebase.

If you really, really, well and truly need to do this (you don't), you should be using a `Factory` to ensure that the correct instances are built/used, and injecting the factory into your application, rather than the classes themselves.

If you are seriously ***depending, wholesale, upon the `typeof` or `instanceof` functionality to ensure the sturdiness of your application -- especially in such a way that the check requires circular references, then your application is not sturdy in the first place***

Your classes should not need to know about one another, and when you delegate their construction to factories, if that's the path you choose to take, then the classes should not know about the factory, either.

Comment: Editted post concerning what I am trying to achieve! Is what I am looking to do sound like an anti pattern?

Comment: @MichaelPetrochuk based on your update, `Phrase` should not parse itself, but rather, should be parsed. The antipattern is not in what you're trying to achieve, but how you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: @MichaelPetrochuk It sounds like in C/C++/Go/etc, `Phrase` would be a simple `struct`, which a `Parser` instance (or static methods) would operate on.  It's only really with the popularity of Java that `struct` and `class` get used for the same purpose, all the time. If you must, you can still use `class Phrase`, just treat it as a struct. `Parser.parse( phrase )`, with an `instanceof` check inside is really no more safe than with a check for `(phrase && phrase.content)` check. You can make it safer just by saying `content = (phrase && phrase.content) || ""` and duck-typing from there.

Comment: I thought you couldn't use es6 modules in node and that you had to use the commonJs modules instead with require.

Comment: @mjwrazor for now. If you choose not to use Rollup, Webkit, Babel, tsc or any other code-preparation step.

That said, modules will be included natively; it's just a matter of timeline.

Comment: @Norguard so you use those on the node js back End?

Comment: @mjwrazor I've seen Node written in TypeScript, yes. And Node written with Flow annotations. I've used server-side rendering in React...

Bundling all of your scripts together with Rollup would also shave a lot of code off, as well as cut down on time loading your modules. Before the 6.9 LTS build of Node, I was using Babel to support nearly the entire suite of ES6 features... so yeah. There are a lot of good reasons to use those things on the back end.

Comment: @Norguard, but can you write an npm package with typescript. One that has nothing to do with the front end or a server. I am writing pretty much something like an repl and would like to use Typescript.

Comment: @mjwrazor  Just provide types for it, and compile it as a pre-publish step (pre-publish as in before you publish, not necessarily in the `prepublish` hook)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134723/discussion-between-mjwrazor-and-norguard).

Answer (score 3):

You are recursively calling each module from inside the other,  so when you import b in the a module,  it is not ready yet.

You should not require a.js inside the b module.

If for some reason you need to do it,  refactor your code because this is an antipattern.

You could use a third module which require a and b like this:

```
const A = require('a'); //Export the class, not the instance
const B = require('b'); //Export the class, not the instance

var a = new A();
var b = new B();

a.b = b;
```

This way you are also sure that a and b are instances of their respective classes, or if you prefer you can still use the required classes for `instanceof`.

Also,  if I can suggest,  use uppercase naming for your Classes.

Comment: Your right! That is what is happening. But I do need to do this to use the instanceof operator. 

class B in my code needs to check inside a function "abc instanceof a". class A needs to instantiate an instance of B as part of its functionality. How do I work around that?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know why you should check if "abc instanceof a" inside b, as i havent seen your code. The fact itself that you need to do it make me think that you are mixing the roles of the two classes in your application. You could probably use a third class, which does the work of requiring a and b and checking for them.

Answer (score 1):

Might be complicating more this then it might be.

Check out this simple class of a light.

```
class Light {
  constructor(state = false) {
    this.state = state;
  }
  on() {
    this.state = true;
    return this.state;
  }
  off() {
    this.state = false;
    return this.state;
  }
}

const myLight = new Light();
myLight.on()
```

You can see that the state is defined in the constructor.

Hope this helps.